# Why is window.location undefined on all properties in Safari 6 and Mobile Safari (iOS 6)

Tags: safari, mobile-safari

When I type

```
window.location
```

I get undefined on all properties.

Here's my console:

[image]

Comment: Logging `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(location));` works fine (methods such as `reload` are lost, but you don't need these for inspection anyway).

Answer (score 5):

This code works in Safari (6.0.1) and earlier

```
    // Get location for REST TARGETS

    lcnURI = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.hostname + ":"
            + window.location.port + "/rest/";
```

It appears that window.location "goes out of context" when you look at in the log.  But in place used it's fine.

Comment: The thing is I'm expecting all of the properties of the location object, not just the URI.

Answer (score 4):

I can confirm this (Version 6.0 (8536.25)). Seems to be a Safari bug, as far as I can tell.

Tested on jsbin (http://jsbin.com/enugoj/1/):

```
console.log(window.location);
console.log(window.location.pathname);​
```

Results in Safari's console:

```
Location
  ancestorOrigins: undefined
  hash: undefined
  host: undefined
  hostname: undefined
  href: undefined
  origin: undefined
  pathname: undefined
  port: undefined
  protocol: undefined
  search: undefined
  __proto__: LocationPrototype

/enugoj/1
```

Results in Chrome (Version 21.0.1180.89):

```
Location
  ancestorOrigins: DOMStringList
  assign: function () { [native code] }
  hash: ""
  host: "jsbin.com"
  hostname: "jsbin.com"
  href: "http://jsbin.com/enugoj/1"
  origin: "http://jsbin.com"
  pathname: "/enugoj/1"
  port: ""
  protocol: "http:"
  reload: function () { [native code] }
  replace: function () { [native code] }
  search: ""
  toString: function toString() { [native code] }
  valueOf: function valueOf() { [native code] }
  __proto__: Location
  1:14

/enugoj/1
```

Comment: Yep that is exactly what I get...all undefined :(